# Manually show specific posts on homepage

Tags: php, wordpress

To loop and show all WordPress posts we use:

```
<?php 
    if( have_posts() ) :
         while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
<?php 
   endwhile;
   endif;
?>
```

And to show only the first recent post we use:

```
<?php 
    if( have_posts() ) :
         if( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
<?php 
   endif;
   endif;
?>
```

My question is, can I manually select what posts I want to show on my homepage without doing a loop? For example let's say I want to only show post1, post3, and post6 on my homepage, can I do that?

Comment: posts or post? Depends. If posts, then do a wp_query and loop it.. If post, then just select a post as your home page may be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
<?php /*
Template Name: Query Single Post
*/
get_header(); ?>
    <?php query_posts('p=40'); ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile;?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The one I picked had an ID of 40. So, I set p=40. On the page I chose to use this on, I selected the "Query Single Post" post template. Clicked save and refreshed my page.

Answer (score 1):

Without using while loop because the post contain only one post.

```
<?php /*
Template Name: Query Single Post
*/
get_header(); ?>
    <?php query_posts('p=>40'); ?>
    <?php if (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endif;?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [pre_get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) filter.

Code:

```
<?php
add_action('pre_get_posts', function($query){
    if ( !$query->is_home() or !$query->is_main_query() )
        return false;

    # And here you can use any parameters from [WP_Query Class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)
    # For example
    $query->set('post__in', [10, 15, 16]);
});
```

Comment: How? PLease explain.

Comment: Don't know how use code in comments. Put code [here](http://pastebin.com/XZ3r2aL7)

Comment: Please add it as an answer :)

Comment: Using query_posts on pages make an additional load. _pre_get_posts_ change query parameters before making query. So you get only what you need and saves server resources.

Comment: let me add it for you (you still should explain why this code works). I am cancelling the neg vote after i edit this ( if possible to)..